Ignoring codec because it collides with previously generated codec
i am trying to register custom code(for map) like below
    val session: CqlSession = CassandraConnector.apply(spark.sparkContext).openSession()
    val codecRegistry: MutableCodecRegistry = session.getContext.getCodecRegistry.asInstanceOf[MutableCodecRegistry];
    val codec: CustomMapCodec = new CustomMapCodec()
    codecRegistry.register(codec)

but getting error
Ignoring codec CustomMapCodec@3791af because it collides with previously generated codec com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.MapCodec@66fff42f
does anyone how can i do it?
i am using spark-cassandra-connector_2.12 and version 2.5.2 in my scala application.
tried registering the custom codec in my CqlSession object as described in documentation: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.17/manual/core/custom_codecs/index.html

I faced similar issue not exactly the same one, when I removed manual registering of codec from the code it worked for me.
